# Little help with null space of a matrix

Tags: math, matlab

This requires a little knowledge about Matlab and I have none. I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction and give me some pointer :)

I have to write a matlab code for finding the Null spaces of matices
A and B, where B = A^T x A. And then nd the general solutions to AX = b1
and BX = b2, where b1= the column [1 2 3 4 5] and b2= the column [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8].
My concern is that I dont really know how to go about this code. 
This is what I have so far and I do not think i am in the right track. I have a specific matrix as below. 
The rows are divided by semi-colon.

```
A = [ 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8;
      1   2^2 3^2 4^2 5^2 6^2 7^2 8^2;
      1   2^3 3^3 4^3 5^3 6^3 7^3 8^3;
      1   2^4 3^4 4^4 5^4 6^4 7^4 8^4;
      6   8   1   1   7   9   0   7 ]
B = A’A (this is how transpose is written) 
C = null(A)
D = null(B)
```

I feel like there should be a rref somewhere - I'm just not getting anywhere. Please point me in the right direction.

---

Ok so I updated it to the this now....My username changed from jona and I dont know why

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;
1 2^2 3^2 4^2 5^2 6^2 7^2 8^2;
1 2^3 3^3 4^3 5^3 6^3 7^3 8^3;
1 2^4 3^4 4^4 5^4 6^4 7^4 8^4;
6 8 1 1 7 9 0 7 ] 

B = A’*A (this is how transpose is written)

null(A)

null(B)

b1=[1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ];

b2=[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8 ];

end

rref(A,b1)

rref(B,b2)

end
```

However I still don't feel this is right :(

@Chris A. I know the null space is the solution to Ax=0. However I'm confused on how to use it to find general solution using the b1 and b2 I have. Is it possible for you to explain to me the connection? I don't undertand the book as much.

Comment: Ok, so now you've made the matrices and gotten orthonormal bases for the null spaces.  Do you understand what a null space means and how to use it in creating the general solutions?  You need the have a grasp on the math here before you write the code, obviously.

Comment: Jona - can you refrain from asking the same question over and over. If you need to get more attention for your questions then edit the originals with more relevant information about your problem, this will "bump" the question. Thanks.

Comment: I've fixed up your registered account and merged the unregistered one for you. I also popped your answer back into the question as an edit, so you should be all good to go.

Comment: I explained it below. You need to think about what the general solution means.  Pay specific attention to the part where you plug the general solution back in and see what happens to the `A*C` part.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, [arithmetic operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) need to be explicit, i.e. `a(b+c)` should be written as `a*(b+c)`

Have you tried writing `B` as

```
B=A'*A;
```

---

Also, you seem to be using a different character for the transpose... You're using `’`, the unicode character for [single right quotation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) when you should be using `'` or the unicode character for [apostrophe](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the bottom line is that the null space is the set of all vectors `x` such that `A * x = 0`.  You got that right.  And `C` is an orthonormal basis for the vectors in the null space.  So that means if you have a particular solution (let's call it `v`) such that `A * v = b1` then the space of solutions is the vector `v` plus any combination of vectors in the null space.

For the case of `A`, the size (second dimension) of your `C` will tell you the dimension of the null space.  Each one of the vectors in `C` will be a vector in the null space.

To get `v` you can do `v = A \ b1`. You can write arbitrary combinations of vectors in `C` by `C * c` where little `c` is a column vector that is the size of the null space.

The general solution is thus  `v + C * c` where `c` is any vector that is the dimension of the null space.  To see that this solve the system, just plug it back in

```
A * (v + C * c) = 
A * v + A * C * c =
b1 + 0 * c = 
b1
```

Edit: It's the exact same idea for finding the solution to `A'*A * x = b2`, just anywhere you see `A` in the above discussion, replace it with `A'*A` and anywhere you see `b1` replace it with `b2`.  The solutions to `A * x = b1` and `A'*A * x = b2` are separate problems.